# Facebook Integration on Libgdx

Tags: android, facebook, libgdx

I'm developing a android game using libgdx. I wanted to share my game score to Facebook.

Can anyone help me with it? I am very new to libgdx so a tutorial link will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read about platform specific code in libgdx: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

And after that just use the official documentation on Facebook Android API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Answer (score 3):

LibGdx is cross platform gaming framework so it's better to use this

https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook

This is libGDX extension providing cross-platform support for Facebook Graph API.
Hopefully this may be useful.